# ActiveMQ: consumer to Broker authentication using JAAS and certificate fails

Tags: java, ssl, https, activemq-classic, jaas

I am trying to get authentication and authorization working with `ActiveMQ 5.11.0` and I'm getting the below security exception when I try to connect the consumer to the broker after trying to use `<JaasCertificateAuthenticationPlugin>`.

I tried over ssl and works fine, but with https protocol no. Without the plugin `jaas` the handshake works fine in both protocols.

```
 INFO | Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@10123eee: startup date [Tue Feb 03 12:55:29 CET 2015]; root of context hierarchy 
 INFO | PListStore:[d:\Pruebas\apache-activemq-5.10.1\bin\..\data\localhost\tmp_storage] started 
 INFO | Using Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[d:\Pruebas\apache-activemq-5.10.1\bin\..\data\kahadb] 
 INFO | KahaDB is version 5 
 INFO | Recovering from the journal ... 
 INFO | Recovery replayed 29 operations from the journal in 0.017 seconds. 
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.10.1 (localhost, ID:mortegahpw7-61946-1422964530870-0:1) is starting 
 INFO | Listening for connections at: ssl://mortegahpw7:61614?needClientAuth=true 
 INFO | Connector ssl started 
 INFO | Connector https started 
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.10.1 (localhost, ID:mortegahpw7-61946-1422964530870-0:1) started 
 INFO | For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org
 INFO | ActiveMQ WebConsole available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/
 INFO | Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher' 
 INFO | jolokia-agent: No access restrictor found at classpath:/jolokia-access.xml, access to all MBeans is allowed 
 WARN | Failed to add Connection ID:mortegahpw7-50778-1422964583957-2:1 
java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to authenticate transport without SSL certificate. 
        at org.apache.activemq.security.JaasCertificateAuthenticationBroker.addConnection(JaasCertificateAuthenticationBroker.java:74)[activemq-broker-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1] 
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.MutableBrokerFilter.addConnection(MutableBrokerFilter.java:102)[activemq-broker-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1] 
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processAddConnection(TransportConnection.java:809)[activemq-broker-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1] 
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagedTransportConnection.processAddConnection(ManagedTransportConnection.java:79)[activemq-broker-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1] 
        at org.apache.activemq.command.ConnectionInfo.visit(ConnectionInfo.java:139)[activemq-client-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1] 
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.service(TransportConnection.java:334)[activemq-broker-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1] 
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$1.onCommand(TransportConnection.java:188)[activemq-broker-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1] 
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.AbstractInactivityMonitor.onCommand(AbstractInactivityMonitor.java:270)[activemq-client-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1] 
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportSupport.doConsume(TransportSupport.java:83)[activemq-client-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1] 
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.http.HttpTunnelServlet.doPost(HttpTunnelServlet.java:143)[activemq-http-5.10.1.jar:5.10.1] 
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:713)[geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec-1.2.jar:1.2] 
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)[geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec-1.2.jar:1.2] 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:652)[jetty-all-server-7.6.9.v20130131.jar:7.6.9.v20130131] 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:445)[jetty-all-server-7.6.9.v20130131.jar:7.6.9.v20130131] 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)[jetty-all-server-7.6.9.v20130131.jar:7.6.9.v20130131] 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:301)[jetty-all-server-7.6.9.v20130131.jar:7.6.9.v20130131] 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1046)[jetty-all-server-7.6.9.v20130131.jar:7.6.9.v20130131] 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:372)[jetty-all-server-7.6.9.v20130131.jar:7.6.9.v20130131] 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:978)[jetty-all-server-7.6.9.v20130131.jar:7.6.9.v20130131] 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)[jetty-all-server-7.6.9.v20130131.jar:7.6.9.v20130131] 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)[jetty-all-server-7.6.9.v20130131.jar:7.6.9.v20130131] 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:367)[jetty-all-server-7.6.9.v20130131.jar:7.6.9.v20130131] 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:486)[jetty-all-server-7.6.9.v20130131.jar:7.6.9.v20130131] 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:937)[jetty-all-server-7.6.9.v20130131.jar:7.6.9.v20130131] 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:998)[jetty-all-server-7.6.9.v20130131.jar:7.6.9.v20130131] 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:861)[jetty-all-server-7.6.9.v20130131.jar:7.6.9.v20130131] 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)[jetty-all-server-7.6.9.v20130131.jar:7.6.9.v20130131] 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)[jetty-all-server-7.6.9.v20130131.jar:7.6.9.v20130131] 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SslConnection.handle(SslConnection.java:196)[jetty-all-server-7.6.9.v20130131.jar:7.6.9.v20130131] 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)[jetty-all-server-7.6.9.v20130131.jar:7.6.9.v20130131] 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)[jetty-all-server-7.6.9.v20130131.jar:7.6.9.v20130131] 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)[jetty-all-server-7.6.9.v20130131.jar:7.6.9.v20130131] 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)[jetty-all-server-7.6.9.v20130131.jar:7.6.9.v20130131] 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_71] 
 WARN | Security Error occurred: Unable to authenticate transport without SSL certificate. 
 INFO | Stopping blockingQueue_1198464663 because Failed with SecurityException: Unable to authenticate transport without SSL certificate.
```

Snippet of the ActiveMq broker configuration showing the certificates and transports connectors

```
<transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector name="ssl" uri="ssl://0.0.0.0:61614?needClientAuth=true"/>
            <transportConnector name="https" uri="https://0.0.0.0:61618?needClientAuth=true"/>
        </transportConnectors>



<sslContext>
         <sslContext keyStore="file:${activemq.base}/cert/broker.ks" 
                                 keyStorePassword=password 
                                 trustStore="file:${activemq.base}/cert/broker.ts" 
                                 trustStorePassword=password />
  </sslContext>


<plugins>
            <jaasCertificateAuthenticationPlugin configuration="CertLogin" />
</plugins>
```

> login.conf

```
CertLogin { 
    org.apache.activemq.jaas.TextFileCertificateLoginModule required 
        debug=true 
        org.apache.activemq.jaas.textfiledn.user="users.properties" 
        org.apache.activemq.jaas.textfiledn.group="groups.properties"; 
};
```

> user.properties

```
admin=admin 
system=CN=Broker,\ OU=broker,\ O=broker,\ L=M,\ ST=M,\ C=SP 
user=CN=Manolo,\ OU=Manolo,\ O=Manolo,\ L=M,\ ST=M,\ C=SP 
guest=CN=anon,O=Progress,C=DE
```

The code of the consumer

```
String url = "https://localhost:61618";
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","d:\\cert\\client.ks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", password);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", password);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","d:\\cert\\client.ts");
ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory();
connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(url);
Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
connection.start();
```

Is there anything I missing?

Appreciate for your help, 
Manolo

Comment: You should also document the URI value passed to the connection factory setBrokerURL method.

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question and added the URI and the transports connectors